# How to record time taken by a cron to execute.

Tags: linux, logging, cron

I have a cron set to run every minute

```
* * * * * /usr/php /my/location/script.php
```

Now, I use [time](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time) function to measure script execution time. So, running

```
console$ time /usr/php /my/location/script.php
```

outputs

```
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

But it doesn't work with cron like this:

```
* * * * * time /usr/php /my/location/script.php 2>&1 >> my_log_file
```

neither does it work on command line

```
console$ time /usr/php /my/location/script.php >> my_log_file
```

In both of the above examples, the time function actually calculates the time taken to write to my_log_file, instead of writing its output to the log file. 
Adding code in the script and recording STD OUTPUT is NOT AN OPTION.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about:

```
 * * * * *    (time /usr/php /my/location/script.php) >>my_log_file 2>&1
```

Comment: You sir, saved my day. 'Just because today is a lazy day' do you mind explaining what you did ? and how did the parenthesis help?

Comment: the parens startup a shell and thus you run the contents between the parens under a shell...and send its output to the redirected locations.

Comment: I am getting this output with this command `1.16user 0.23system 0:07.84elapsed 17%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 80240maxresident)k` and it missing the real time. Do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

How about the in-built cron daemon feature?

Check your cron daemon's man page. Many have a "-L" argument to specify a log level. Eg on Ubuntu (ie, Debian):

```
 -L loglevel
           Sets  the loglevel for cron. The standard logging level (1) will log the
           start of all the cron jobs. A higher loglevel (2) will cause cron to log
           also the end of all cronjobs, which can be useful to audit the behaviour
           of tasks run by cron. Logging will be disabled if the loglevel is set to
           zero (0).
```

Comment: This option seems promising, could you please show an example on how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is using the `time` shell builtin vs. the `time` binary. Using the builtin it doesn't work, even with the proper redirection:

```
$ time pwn >> foo 2>&1

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.002s

$ cat foo 
/tmp
```

Using the binary works:

```
$ /usr/bin/time pwd >> foo 2>&1
$ cat foo 
/tmp
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 564maxresident)k
64inputs+8outputs (1major+175minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

With GNU time you can use the `-o` and `-a` options instead of shell redirection:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -o foo -a pwd
/tmp
$ cat foo 
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 564maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+179minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems `time` is bash builtin (at least on my system). Following works for me: `/bin/bash -c 'time ls' > out.std 2> out.err`. Output of `time` would be in stderr (out.err file).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try putting

```
/usr/bin/time /usr/php /my/location/script.php
```

Into a script and then calling that script from your cron job.

As an aside, is your php binary really in /usr? Or /usr/bin?

Comment: Nope that didn't work and my php is in /usr/bin ... I was typing this instead of copying, so missed it.:p

Comment: How did it fail?

Comment: It didn't fail. It just doesn't write to the file, It writes to output after the command is executed. I want the times to be recorded to a log file

Comment: Yeah..I get it. I've been noodling around here for a few trying to come up with the magic recipe. I'm sure some command line wizard will come along soon and sort it out for you.